# Textarea: Showing wrong qty of characthers that I can write

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have a little problem here setting limit characters for a textarea.

I have been trying to show the limit of characters that I can write and also the character keys that I can continue writing.

The limit is 10 characters but when I press the first key, the output keeps showing 10 "spaces" to continue writing. And when I write the last character (in theory) the output shows is possible press another one more, but this is like a non-visible character.

Maybe I've forgotten how to do math, but I appreciate any help with this (and If there is some else wrong with the code, please tell me).

This is the HTML part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea id='text'></textarea>
  <br />
  <span>Characters <span id='info'></span></span>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the JavaScript:

```
function showTill(limit){

var getId = document.getElementById('text');

  var shot = getId.onkeydown = exe;

  function exe(stuff){

  var getSpan= document.getElementById('info');
  var printSpan = getSpan.innerHTML = limit - getId.value.length; //prints qty of character keys I can write yet.

  var evento = stuff || window.event;
  var combine = evento.which || evento.keyCode; 
  var omitDel = combine === 8 || combine === 46; //Enabling Backspace and Delete after reaching the limit of character written.
  var omitArrow = combine === 37 || combine === 39; //Enabling Right/Left Arrows after reaching the limit of character written.    

  if (getId.value.length >= limit && !omitDel && !omitArrow){ 
    return false;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
  }
}


showTill(10);
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What's "qty"? I searched my friendly neighborhood dictionary but couldn't find a definition for it.

Comment: Side note, is the double doctype a typo?

Comment: I just made a JSfiddle by copying/pasting the relevant code from above http://jsfiddle.net/FGXTv/ and it seems to work ok for me.

Comment: It seems that the first keydown is somehow ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what is happending the explanation is in event handling.

You are catching `onkeydown` event. So, the first time some key is pressed, event is fired, `getId.value.length` shows `0`, which is correct. There is no character at that time. Character is shown later, when event handler has already finished with his job. So you show `Character 10` after first pressed char. Now, press another one and `getId.value` returns `1`: length 1 because there is only one char at that time, the second one is comming but is not there yet...

And you press 10 chars but `Character` field shows `1`.

You would get similar behaviour for `onkeypress`

We have to count in the first "missed" char. I would change the event handling function to

```
function exe(stuff) {
    var printSpan;

    var getSpan = document.getElementById('info');
    //var printSpan = getSpan.innerHTML = limit - (getId.value.length + 1); //prints qty of character keys I can write yet.

    var evento = stuff || window.event;
    var combine = evento.which || evento.keyCode; 
    var isDel = combine === 8 || combine === 46; //Enabling Backspace and Delete after reaching the limit of character written.
    var isArrow = combine === 37 || combine === 39; //Enabling Right/Left Arrows after reaching the limit of character written.    

    if ((getId.value.length + 1) > limit && !isDel && !isArrow) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (isArrow) {
            // do nothing
            return true;
        }

        if (isDel)
            printSpan = getSpan.innerHTML = limit - (getId.value.length - 1);
        else
            printSpan = getSpan.innerHTML = limit - (getId.value.length + 1);

        return true;
    }
}
```